# Modify the code to handle trees with weighted edges and loops with BFS and DFS

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

I am currently studying for an internship interview.

I got the following question:

> Tree search algorithms. Write BFS and DFS code, explain run time and space requirements.
>       Modify the code to handle trees with weighted edges  and loops with BFS and DFS, make the code print out path to goal state.

I previously implement DFS and BFS buy using stack and queue to traverse a tree.

For example,

```java
void DFS(Node n) {
    Stack S  = new Stack(); 
    s.push(rootNode);
    rootNode.visited = true;
    if (s is not empty) {
    Node n = s.peek();
    if (n's visited is false) {
        s.push(n);
    }
    else {
        s.pop();
    }
}
```

However, I am not really sure how to handle "trees with weighted edges"

What should I do for this part?

Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: BFS and DFS will work with weighted edges if you only need to print out any path from source to target (not shortest).

Comment: Do you need to find the shortest path (weight) to the target or just to find an available path?

Comment: Pham Trung // how can I calculate weighted edge. is it like (left height - right height) ?

Comment: gloompisces// yep, but question doesn't mention about shortest path(weight). I am not really sure how to get weight and how output look like..